# Python: Insertion sort algorithm to sort the lines of a csv based on one column

Tags: python, sorting, insertion-sort

I'm trying to find a way to sort a csv file based on one column, without using in built sorts. I've been messing with an insertion sort program to try to get it to do so but I'm pretty lost. Here's what I've got so far:

```
def insertSort(fileobj,colno):
    sline = line.split(',')
    l=0
    for line in fileobj:
        l += 1
    for i in range(2,l):
        thisline = fileobj.split(",")[i]
        key = thisline[colno]
        j = i-1
        temp = fileobj.split(",")[j]
        lastline = temp[colno]
        while j>=1 and key < lastline:
            fileobj[j+1]=fileobj[j]
            j -= 1
        fileobj[j+1] = key
```

Where colno would be the index of the column you're trying to sort by, and assuming the first row is the header. I am new to python so am I missing something fundamental? Would it be easier to convert the csv to a dictionary and change my approach?

Edit: forgot to mention that fileobj would be some file that's been opened and readlines() would be assigned to fileobj

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you fix your indentation and make sure your function returns something?

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't try to handle CSV files yourself; there is a CSV library to do it. If the CSV files are tame it's fine, but there are those pesky edge cases (like quoted values containing commas) that can trip you up. Secondly... your code can't possibly work. Starting with the first line of your function, where you use `line` that is not defined anywhere. Also, what is `fileobj`? If it's the result of `open().readlines()`, fine; if it's the result of `open`, you can't read it twice without rewinding. And why are you splitting `fileobj` by commas?

Comment: If I were you, I'd look up [insertion sort] on Wikipedia, then try to rewrite it into Python. Trying to get both Python and algorithm right at the same time might be overwhelming at start. Also note that if fileobj is lines, you can get number of lines using `len(fileobj)`, no need for that `for` loop.

Comment: I've got the normal insertion sort algorithm working on a list fine, I'm just really struggling to understand how to manage it to work as I need it to. I'm basing a lot of this off similar file io stuff I've seen but again I am new so it's not going to be perfect, I just want to know where to go to get on the right track.

Comment: Your code gives: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'line' referenced before assignment`. [Edit] your Questions code to correct or explain `line`.